# Can't add write permission to docker volume in docker-compose

Tags: wordpress, docker, permissions, docker-compose, volumes

## Issue

My main goal is to create a wordpress container on my linux machine for development on that container.

Therefore, I'm creating new volumes for the `plugins` and `themes` folders and even add `read & write` permissions, with the `:rw` option.

However, when I'm trying to create a new directory or file in those "volumes", **I get an error message (especially in VS Code), that tells that I don't have the permission to add these volumes.**

Moreover, the permissions based on the `ll` command shows that the owner is the only one with the `w` permissions. It means that I cannot use the group `www-data` and add it to my user in order to edit those volumes.

When I'm trying to run `chmod 766 themes plugins`, the volumes are not bind anymore, so this solution doesn't work.

I've searched the whole web (including stack overflow), but none of the answers didn't work for me, so I'm lost :(

Here are some details that can help you with finding solution, including the `docker-compose.yml` file.

## Details

### Error on VS Code when trying to add a directory named `hello`

```
A system error occurred (EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '~/Workspace/WordpressProject/themes/hello')
```

### Run `mkdir hello` in terminal, returns this error

`mkdir: cannot create directory ‘hello’: Permission denied`

### `ll` command result for volumes

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 14 23:54 plugins/
drwxr-xr-x 5 www-data www-data 4096 May 17 22:00 themes/
```

### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    links:
      - mariadb:mysql
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=${Database Name}
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.101:80:80"
    hostname: ${Wordpress Host}
    volumes:
      - ./plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins:rw
      - ./themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes:rw
    restart: always
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${Password}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${Database Name}
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
```

### Versions

- **OS:** Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- **Docker:** v18.05.0-ce, API v1.37
- **Editor (Visual Studio Code):** v1.23.1

Comment: Can you post error code?

Comment: added for you at the top of `details` section

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please in VS terminal execute:

```
sudo chown -R $USER <directory_project>
```

Comment: When you say VM do you mean the docker container itself?

Comment: Sorry, I think about VS!